# VirtualBox: Windows Host / Linux Mint guest: guestcontrol running program not working

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint

I'm trying to set up some host integration with my Linux VM and for that I need to get some basic things running, namely, running programs on the guest.

I've tried to use `vboxmanage guestcontrol` but the problem is that I never recieve any output from the started program, nor do they ever terminate.

Here's an example: `vboxmanage guestcontrol "Linux Mint" --username <username> --password <password> run --wait-stdout -- /bin/ls`

I would expect this to produce some output and then terminate when finished, but instead I just get a blinking cursor and it hangs forever. This is the only reaction I get on the client:
[Task Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfqxK.png)

Other tasks such as creating folders using `vboxmanage guestcontrol` seem to work fine.

Host: Windows 10 Home Premium 64bit

Guest: Linux Mint 18.2 (xfce) running on a physical partition